# Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: c

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
I have the following code but the answer does not match.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long unsigned int i,sum=0;
    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        if((i%5==0)||(i%3==0))
        {
            sum=sum+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should link to Project Euler's first problem? ( http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1 )

Comment: I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403964/9210255

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two things:

- you're *including* 1000 in the loop, and
- you're adding one to the sum each time, rather than the value itself.

Change the loop to

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
```

And the sum line to

```
sum=sum+i;
```

Comment: Its printing some garbage.I even changed int to long int

Comment: I get 233168 once those changes are in place, and a warning about the format (see Hugo's Answer).  Is that the right value?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587320/project-euler-1find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000

Comment: You can start the loop from i=3. It will save you three iteration.

Comment: @HarshVardhan While you are right, you might also start from i=5 and set the sum to 3... etc... :-)

Answer (score 24):

Rather than using range/loop based solutions you may wish to leverage more math than brute force.

There is a simple way to get the sum of multiples of a number, less than a number.

For instance, the sum of multiples of 3 up to 1000 are: 3 + 6 + 9 + ... + 999
Which can be rewritten as: 3* ( 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 333)

There is a simple way to sum up all numbers 1-N:

```
Sum(1,N) = N*(N+1)/2
```

So a sample function would be

```
unsigned int unitSum(unsigned int n)
{
    return (n*(n+1))/2;
}
```

So now getting all multiples of 3 less than 1000 (aka up to and including 999) has been reduced to:

```
3*unitSum((int)(999/3))
```

You can do the same for multiples of 5:

```
5*unitSum((int)(999/5))
```

But there is a caveat! Both of these count multiples of both such as 15, 30, etc
It counts them twice, one for each. So in order to balance that out, you subtract once.

```
15*unitSum((int)(999/15))
```

So in total, the equation is:

```
sum = 3*unitSum((int)(999/3)) + 5*unitSum((int)(999/5)) - 15*unitSum((int)(999/15))
```

So now rather than looping over a large set of numbers, and doing comparisons, you are just doing some simple multiplication!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you should do

```
sum += i // or sum = sum + i
```

instead of

```
sum = sum + 1
```

Additionally, be careful when printing `long unsigned int`s with printf. I guess the right specifier is `%lu`.

Answer (score 6):

It should be `sum = sum + i` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y,n;
    int sum=0;
    printf("enter the valeus of x,y and z\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&n);
    printf("entered   valeus of x=%d,y=%d and z=%d\n",x,y,n);
    sum=x*((n/x)*((n/x)+1)/2)+y*((n/y)*((n/y)+1)/2)-x*y*(n/(x*y))*((n/(x*y))+1)/2;
    printf("sum is %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
// give x,y and n  as 3 5 and 1000
```

Comment: This solution is generic to all case.

Comment: Try with no prime numbers x and y, let's say 4 and 10

Answer (score 2):

Here's a python one-liner that gives the correct answer (233168):

```
reduce( lambda x,y: x+y, [ x for x in range(1000) if x/3.0 == int( x/3.0 ) or x/5.0 == int( x/5.0 ) ] )
```

Comment: The code:if x/3.0 == int( x/3.0 ) or x/5.0 == int( x/5.0 )
can be simply made to if x%3==0 or x%5==0

Answer (score 2):

Just as an improvement you might want to avoid the loop altogether :

```
multiples of 3 below 1000 form an AP : 3k where k in [1, 333]
multiples of 5 below 1000 form an AP : 5k where k in [1, 199]
```

If we avoid multiples of both 3 and 5 : 15k where k in [1, 66]

`So the answer is : 333*(3+999)/2 + 199(5+995)/2 - 66*(15+990)/2 = 2331`68

Why you might want to do this is left to you to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting fact of the difference in time between this 2 methods... The second method just calculate only with needed numbers and dont iterate through a loop.
Example: 3 * (1+2+3+4...333)  (Because 3 * 333 = 999 and 999 < 1000.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        Calc calculator = new Calc();
        long target = 999999999;
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " +  (calculator.calcMultipleSumFast(3,target) + calculator.calcMultipleSumFast(5, target) - calculator.calcMultipleSumFast(15, target)));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime: " + sw.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine();
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (calculator.calcMultiplesSum(3, 5,1000000000)));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime: " + sw.Elapsed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Calc
{
    public long calcMultiplesSum(long n1, long n2, long rangeMax)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < rangeMax; i++)
        {
            if ((i % n1 == 0) || (i % n2 == 0))
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public long calcMultipleSumFast(long n, long rangeMax)
    {
        long p = rangeMax / n;

        return (n * (p * (p + 1))) / 2;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the stepping approach, you can make a version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        sum += i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
        if (i % 5) sum += i;  /* already counted */
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

which does a whole lot fewer `modulo` computations.

In fact, with a counter, you can make a version with none:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {

    int sum = 0;
    int cnt = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 5) {
        sum += i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
        if (--cnt == 0) cnt = 5;
        else sum += i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I attempt the **Project Euler #1**: Multiples of 3 and 5. And got 60 points for that.

```
private static long euler1(long N) {
        long i, sum = 0;
        for (i = 3; i < N; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I use Java for it and you can use this logic for C. I worked hard and find an optimal solution.

```
private static void euler1(long n) {
        long a = 0, b = 0, d = 0;

        a = (n - 1) / 3;
        b = (n - 1) / 5;
        d = (n - 1) / 15;

        long sum3 = 3 * a * (a + 1) / 2;
        long sum5 = 5 * b * (b + 1) / 2;
        long sum15 = 15 * d * (d + 1) / 2;
        long c = sum3 + sum5 - sum15;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start by iterating from `3` to `1000` in steps of `3` (3,6,9,12,etc), adding them to the `sum` like,

```
int i = 3, sum = 0;
for (; i < 1000; i += 3) {
  sum += i;
}
```

Then you could iterate from `5` to `1000` by `5` (skipping multiples of `3` since they've already been added) adding those values to the `sum` as well

```
for (i = 5; i < 1000; i += 5) {
  if (i % 3 != 0) sum += i;
}
```

Then display the `sum`

```
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation of the problem. Short, precise and fat.

```
sum=0
for i in range(1000):
    if (i%3==0) or (i%5==0):
        sum=sum+i
print sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Sum(int N) {
long long c = 0;
    N--; //because you want it less than 1000 if less than or equal delete this line
    int n = N/3,b = N/5,u = N/15;
    c+= (n*(n+1))/2 * 3;
    c+= (b*(b+1))/2 * 5;
    c-= (u*(u+1))/2 * 15;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 1001; ++i)
        if(!(i % 3) && !(i % 5))
            count += i;
    std::cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think declaratively - what you want to do, rather than how you want to do.

In plain language, it boils down to exactly what the problem asks you to do:

1. Find all multiples of 3 or 5 in a certain range (in this case 1 to 1000)
2. Add them all up (aggregate sum)

In LINQ, it looks like:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
            .Where(x => (x % 3 == 0) || (x % 5 == 0))
            .Aggregate((accumulate, next) => accumulate += next);
```

Now, you can convert this into an iterative solution - but there is nothing wrong with using a declarative solution like above - because it is more clear and succinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int i,sum=0;                    //initialize sum with 0
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)         //run loop from 0  999 (1000 is not included) because      
                                       //we want less than 1000.  
    {
        if(i%5==0||i%3==0)             //check if it satisfy one of the 
                                       //condition either 
                                        //it divides with 5 or 3 completely 
                                        //i.e remainder0 
        {                                     
            sum+=i;                      //increment sum by that number as 
                                             //particular number 
                                             //satisfy the condition 
        }
    }
    cout<<sum;                                 //print sum the value of sum
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.venkat.test;

public class CodeChallenge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int j, sum=0;

        for ( j = 0; j <=1000; j++) {               
            if((j%5==0)||(j%3==0))
            {
                sum=sum+j;
            }               
        }           
        System.out.println(sum);            
    }    
}
```