# Project Euler 1:Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve math problems with Ruby from the Project Euler. [Here](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1) is the first one I tried:

> If we list all the natural numbers
>   below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5,
>   we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these
>   multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3
>   or 5 below 1000.

Please help me to improve my code.

```
total = 0

(0...1000).each do |i|
  total += i if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
end

puts total
```

Comment: I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403964/9210255

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Much faster (constant time) answer:

```
def sum_multiples(multiple, to)
    n = (to-1) / multiple
    n * (n+1) / 2 * multiple
end

irb(main):001:0> sum_multiples(3, 10) + sum_multiples(5, 10) - sum_multiples(15, 10)
=> 23
irb(main):002:0> sum_multiples(3, 1000) + sum_multiples(5, 1000) - sum_multiples(15, 1000)
=> 233168
```

Why does this work? `sum_multiples` works out the sum of multiples of `multiple` up to but not including `to` (it relies on integer division). It first works out the number of number of multiples being summed (`n`), then multiples the standard formula for the sum of 1..n = n(n+1)/2 by `multiple`. Using this, we can add together the sums for the multiples of 3 and 5. We must then not forget that some numbers are multiples of *both* 3 and 5, so we subtract multiples of 15 (3*5).

Although your answer is more than fast enough for the constraints in this problem (it should run in about 1 millisecond on modern hardware), a faster solution such as the one I provide will give a result on very large numbers.

Comment: This is a simple case of something mathematicians call "inclusion/exclusion."

Comment: @Thomas A really simple case. I think my answer is mathsy enough as is, so didn't want to delve into that end.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first you can skip roughly 666 numbers by starting at 3, incrementing by 3. That way, you're only considering multiples of 3. Then do a second loop, starting from 5, incrementing by 5. Here, you need to check for multiples of 3 (or skip every 3rd generated number, as it just so happens that those will be multiples of 3), as they've been summed before.

This will have you check ~500 numbers, roughly half of the required numbers.

Alternatively, you can see if you can figure out a closed form for the sum (in principle, sum the numbers from 1 to floor(max,N), multiply this by N, do this for both your Ns (3 and 5), but then you'll have to subtract the double-counted numbers, but that's essentially subtracting the same for N=15).

Answer (score 2):

here is my approach  that find i(1, 333) for 3*k (3,6,9 ...) and (1,200) for 5*k.

- Count all the divisible by 3 and calculate sum
- Count all the divisible by 5 and calculate sum
- The number divisible by 15 should be counted one

3*(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 333) + 5*(1 + 2 + 3 .. ) - 15*(1 + 2 ...) which you can formulate this with **n*(n+1)/2** and it is **O(1)** time but I implement my code with loop

and here is my **first Ruby Code** :)

```
total = 0

(0...334).each do |i|
   total += i*3 
end

(0...200).each do |i|
   total += i*5 if (i % 3 != 0) 
end

puts total
```

here is [demo](http://ideone.com/9ZsOC)

Comment: I'll give you "simplest", but perhaps not the most elegant: OP's code requires O(N) time, where N=1000 in the given example. But an O(1) solution exists, and might be more in the spirit of Project Euler.

Comment: this is also O(1) I mean you can formulate it. just the implementation is O(N)

Comment: This uses mutable state, so I wouldn't regard it as ideal.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts (0..1000).select {|n| n%3==0 || n%5==0}.inject(0) {|s,n| s+=n}
```

Comment: This'd be the most maintainable solution, and also one where mutable state is avoided the most.

Comment: No need to use `+=`, `.inject(0) {|s,n| s + n }`. Also: `.inject(0, :+)`. And it's below 1000, so `0...1000`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this exactly as stated in the problem:

```
((1..(999/3)).map {|x| x*3} | (1..(999/5)).map {|x| x*5}).reduce(&:+)
```

But marcog's constant-time answer is way, way better.

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
(0..1000).to_a.reject!{|a| (a%3 != 0 && a%5 != 0) }.inject(0) { |s,v| s += v }
```

As pointed out below, the following was incorrect

```
(0...1000).to_a.reject!{|a| (a%3 == 0 || a%5 == 0) }.inject(0) { |s,v| s += v }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that sum anything that *wasn't* a multiple of 3 or 5?

Comment: reject! removes the items for which the block evaluates to true

Comment: And the block evaluates to true if it's a multiple of 3 or 5. Ergo you're summing anything that isn't a multiple of 3 or 5.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how that even worked, then. Updated for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..999).select { |num| (num % 3 == 0) || (num % 5 == 0) }.reduce(:+)
```

Here we are `#select`ing from a range all `num`s that are divisible by 3 or 5. The result is an `Array`.

We can then chain on `#reduce` and `:+` to sum all of the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
(3...1000).find_all {|n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0}.inject(:+)
```

Ruby is so elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I really like marcog answer.

But anyway here's approach that uses something like [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

```
divisors = [3, 5]
limit = 1000
can_be_divided = Array.new(limit + 1, false)
divisors.each do |d|
  i = d
  while i < limit
    can_be_divided[i] = true
    i += d
  end
end

result = 0
can_be_divided.each_with_index { |v, i| result += i if v }
```

My solution uses O(N) memory and rougly O(D * N) where N is limit and D is amount of divisors.

It does not compete with elegant math solution but maybe you will find it interesting.

I guess the benefit is that with increasing amount of divisors math solution will be harder to calculate since you need to work with denominators. In case of [3, 5] it pretty easy - the only denominator is 15. But what about [3, 5, 7, 11, 13] ? You will have to write code that will find all common denominators and it won't be as easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Sum (x){
  let n = 0
  for (let i = 0; i<x;i++){
    if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0)){
      n = n+i 
    } 
  }console.log(n)
}
Sum(1000)

 1. 



    function Sum (x){
      let n = 0
      for (let i = 0; i<x;i++){
        if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0)){
          n = n+i 
        } 
      }console.log(n)
    }
    Sum(1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Sample {

  public static void main(final String args[]) {

    // Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {

        if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) {
            System.out.println(i);
            // add them
            temp = temp + i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

A simple formula can be nos that are multiple of 3 + number that are multiple of 5 - number that are multiple of 3 and 5
no=10

so total_no=3+2-0=5 (3,5,6,9,10)

total_no=(no/3)+(no/5)-(no/15)

Comment: This post is not at all clear, perhaps try to clarify your answer.