# Efficiently add numbers divisible by 3 or 5

Tags: c

List the sum of numbers that are multiples of either 3 or five, below a given number.

Here's my code, couldn't find anything unnecessary. But hackerrank says it has terminated due to time out, time limit is 2 seconds to give the expected output.
Input first line contains 't' that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by lines, each containing an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calc(int a){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int a0=1; a0<a; a0++){
        if(a0%3==0 || a0%5==0){
            sum+=a0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
}
int main(){ 
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int arr[t];
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[a0]);
    }
    for(int b=0; b<t; b++){
        calc(arr[b]);
           printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
2
10
100
```

Output must be

```
23
2318
```

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, then the sum of these multiples is 23.

Comment: This would fit better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you! This code shows the sum of multiples 3 and 5 below inputted numbers.

Comment: Use math instead of loop.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. If it takes too long you probably have an accidental infinite loop or an unexpectedly exponential algorithm. You don't show us what the input is here, so it's anyone's guess as to what's going wrong.

Comment: You also need to pay careful attention to indentation and keep your code uncluttered and clean. C is a very unforgiving language, a single missing character can wreck your day, so it's important to be able to see things at a glance and for mistakes to stand out. It also helps us considerably when reviewing your code.

Comment: As @Yunnosch says don't use a loop to calculate the sum. Use the math formula based on the famous Triangular number formula for summing the integers between 1 and n, i.e. n(n+1) / 2.  So, for n = 4, the sum is 4 * 5 / 2 = 10.  You need to figure out how to use this formula when you are adding up all the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about C: challenge sites expect you to work out the answer for yourself.

Comment: That is the deal: not just solving the test cases, but finding an efficient way of beating the clock: ***that*** is the challenge.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of [Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 gives a wrong answer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51512180/298225) except this asks about time instead of correctness.

Answer (score 5):

## Option 1

You're trying to sum all multiples of 3 or 5 under a given number. Have you tried thinking about how you could do it without a for loop? Let's try. Hm, "3 or 5" is a lot to think about. Let's simplify it, and try to sum all multiples of 3 under 99:

`3+6+9+12+15+...+99`

How could you optimize this addition to avoid a for loop? (Do that before continuing to read)

Now, if you know how to sum all multiples of 3 under a given n, does that give you a way to sum all multiples of 3 *or* 5 under a given n? Hm, what overlaps between the sequences 3,6,9,12,**15**,...,n and 5,10,**15**...,n? Maybe if you can sum multiples of 3 under n, and sum multiples of 5 under n, then you can get rid of that [overlap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

## Option 2

Okay, let's say I know the sum of multiples of 3 or 5 under the number n. Does that help me find the sum of multiples of 3 or 5 under the number n+1? Maybe I know what calc(n) is in terms of calc(n-1). If I could do that then that'll be great, because rather than recalculating calc(n-1), I could just [save](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-1/) calc(n-1) instead. If only...

Comment: A neat trick for estimating time, is that a standard processor can handle ~500M operations a second (more like 2B but every line of C translates to several lines of assembly). So if `t` is 50k, then your outer loop executes 50k times, and then your inner loop executes another 50k times every _single_ time your outer loop iterates. That's (50k)^2 operations! Much larger than the 1B you have available in 2 seconds. Thus the strategy would be to shave one of the loops, usually the inner loop.

Comment: You can use that 500M technique to figure out that your method was incorrect, before having to actually write it and run it.

Comment: Option 1 eliminates the inner loop. For a clue on how to avoid the inner for loop, search for "gauss sum integers".  That provides the formula for summing the integers from 1 to N, and the same method applies to multiples.

Comment: Option 2 optimizes the outer loop, by taking advantage of calculations already done.  For example, if the numbers were all 10000, would it make sense to calculate the result for 10000 every time, or remember it?  What if it asks for 10000 and then 10001, does it make sense to recalculate all initial 10000?  BTW, this outer-loop optimization is called "Dynamic programming."

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints and links for everyone:

- There are `m = (a - 1) / k` numbers below `a` that are divisible by `k` (with integer division).
- Their sum is  `m * (m + 1) / 2 * k` (by [Gaussian sum formula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel), link to German wiki - they seem to like Gauß more).
- The sum of all numbers smaller than `a` divisible by `3` or `5` is the same as

  ```
  + the sum of all numbers smaller than `a` divisible by `3` 
  + the sum of all numbers smaller than `a` divisible by `5` 
  - the sum of all numbers smaller than `a` divisible by `15`
  ```

  (by [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle))

This gives you the constant-time algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* sums the numbers 
   smaller than `a` that 
   are divisible by `k`
*/
int s(int a, int k) {
    int m = (a - 1) / k;
    return m * (m + 1) / 2 * k;
}

/* sums the numbers smaller than
   a that are divisible by both
   3 and 5
*/
int calc(int a) {
    return s(a, 3) + s(a, 5) - s(a, 15);
}

int main(){ 
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int arr[t];
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[a0]);
    }
    for(int b=0; b<t; b++){
        printf("input = %d\n", arr[b]);
        printf("%d\n", calc(arr[b]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./sumFizzBuzz 
4
10
100 
1000
10000
23
2318
233168
23331668
```

Sorry, this had to be, there was just too much loops-&-nonsense here and on the "nearly duplicate" question...

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calc_faster(int a)
{
    int mid=0,sum=0;
    for(unsigned int i = a-1;i>0;i--)
    {if(i%3==0)
      {
          if(i%5==0)
          {
              mid=i;
              break;
          } else sum+=i;
      } else if(i%5==0) sum+=i;
    }
    sum+=mid*(7*mid+15)/30;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
}
int main()
{
       unsigned int t;
       unsigned int temp;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    unsigned int arr[t];
    for(register unsigned int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[a0]);
    }
    for(register unsigned int b=0; b<t; b++)
    {
       calc_faster(arr[b]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please add explanatory text, rather than just code.

Comment: i change algorithm

Comment: `register` is a holdover from when compilers couldn't optimize very well.  These days it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: The `mid*(7*mid+15)/30` term is clever, but not very helpful to most people, without an explanation.