# Finding multiples of 3 or 5 below 'n'

Tags: python

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my code.
What i'm trying to do is create a function that will tell me what the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 are below a given 'number'.

Here's what I've got:

```
def solution(number):
    sum = 0
    for numbers in range(1,number):
        if number%3 == 0 or number%5 == 0:
            sum += number
    return sum
```

It gives me 90. I need 23 (the sum of 3, 5, 6, 9)

Comment: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a bad variable name in Python

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639476/efficiently-add-numbers-divisible-by-3-or-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `number` (the function argument) instead of `numbers` (the loop variable).

Perhaps this is why you should be using descriptive and distinguishable variable names. In your case, you are using two very similar variable names, while also rebinding the name of a built-in function `sum`. This wouldn't happen if the code looked more like:

```
def solution(number):
    total = 0
    for n in range(1, number):
        if n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0:
            total += n
    return total
```

or more concisely:

```
def solution(number):
    return sum(n for n in range(1, number) if n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0)
```

Comment: To say a little more, I think the variable names are a bit confounding. That may be why OP is having the issue.

Comment: I am very conflicted about this. On the one hand, it's a good and complete answer. On the other hand, its a comment giving the reason to close the question as "typo". +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, cleared it right up for me :) Still pretty new to this, i'll adapt.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is a typo repeated four times in three lines of code. I guess it still qualifies as one, but it warrants a mini-lecture on variable names, so I decided to post it as an answer.

Comment: Makes sense. It's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is fine, but you've messed up the variables unfortunately !

"Sum" is actually a built-in function in Python that returns the sum of a list of numbers.

Also, your code is not actually iterating over the numbers in the given range, but just using the value that is passed to the function in the for loop. This is because you chose the same variable name!

Number is also generally not a good variable name. Many dependencies might have built-in functions with this name.

Try your code like so:

```
def solution(threshold):
    result = 0
    for elem in range(threshold):
        if elem % 3 == 0 or elem % 5 == 0:
            result += elem
    return(result)
```

Comment: Good answer but someone beat you to it by a few minutes.  Welcome to StackOverflow!