# How to solve this? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have recently come across a website that has puzzles to solve using code. I am on problem one (sad right?) and alrighty got stuck. Here is the puzzle:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I am using this code:

```
var calculation = function(){

  var result = 0;
  var maxNumber = 1000;
  var resultStr = "";

  for(var i = 0; i <= maxNumber; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
      result = result + i;
      resultStr = resultStr + i;
    }
  }
  alert("Your anwser is: " + result);
  alert("Your anwser is: " + resultStr.split(""));
}

calculation();
```

*EDIT: I have changed my code to this to separate the digits, but my answer is still the same.

```
var calculation = function(){

var result = 0;
var maxNumber = 1000;
var resultStr = "";

for(var i = 0; i <= maxNumber; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
        result = result + i;
        resultStr = resultStr + "-" + i;
    }
}
alert("Your anwser is: " + result);
alert("Your anwser is: " + resultStr.split("-"));
```

}

calculation();

Explanation: A have a function named `calculation` that has three variables. Inside the function there is a `for loop` that counts up from `0 to 1000` and checks every number to see if it is evenly divided by `3` or by `5`. If it is then it is added to the `resultStr` variable a.k.a. Result String that is more for debugging purposes. Then it adds it to the `result` variable that houses the total sum of all the numbers that were evenly divisible by `3` and `5`. Then the program prints out the `result` variable a.k.a. the sum. Only one problem... The program can't determine anything past a single digit. When I print out the sum, all I get is things like: 1 . So the sum isn't reliable. The output is `234168`. I am kinda a noob at javascript so anything will help! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847878/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's amazing what one '=' sign can do!

Answer (score 2):

The problem says:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 **below** 1000

Emphasis mine.

Comment: `Emphasis mine.` **I'm taking that emphasis back.**

Answer (score 0):

**

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

**

**for(var i = 0; i <= maxNumber; i++)**

You need to go up to 1000-1! so remove the = sign.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you should go to <1000 with the for instead of <=1000.

The problem with resultStr is you concatenate all the numbers without a delimiter. With 2 small changes that is fixed

```
var calculation = function(){
    var result = 0;
    var maxNumber = 1000;
    var resultStr = "";

    for(var i = 0; i <= maxNumber; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
            result = result + i;
            resultStr = resultStr + "," + i;
        }
    }
    alert("Your anwser is: " + result);
    alert("Your anwser is: " + resultStr.split(","));
}
```