# Add every number below 20 divisible by 3 and 5

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to this whole PHP business, and trying to do the first challenge at ProjectEuler.com. Simple question: What numbers below 1000 are divisible by 3 and/or 5? Add those numbers together.

Because my code started to spew out incredible long strings of numbers, I just stuck to 20 for now.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
for ($test = 1; $test <= 20; $test++) {

    $total = 0;

    if (($test % 3 == 0) && ($test % 5 == 0)) {
    $total += $test;
    }
    elseif ($test % 3 == 0) {
    $total += $test;
    }
    elseif ($test % 5 == 0) {
    $total += $test;
    }

}

echo $total;

?>
```

I feel this is a pretty logical approach to the situation, although it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Kind regards, Sander

/E: Thanks to everyone helping out!

Comment: `$total = $total += $test;` - double assignment, that's the problem

Comment: Semantically, `$total = $total += $test;` is sort of superfluous, since you could either write it as: (1) `$total = $total + $test;` or (2) `$total += $test;`

Comment: I tried without, didn't work.

Comment: You are resetting the $total every time you iterate the loop, try moving it outside of your for-loop as in my answer below.

Comment: you don't even search for solution :( it's more simplest than you've write   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/project-euler-1-multiples-of-3-and-5 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847878/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000   .. there you need just calcultate 3 separated numbers, add two of them (3 and 5 division) and substract (numbers that divides both of them like 15) the third

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't initialize `$total` inside your loop. Otherwise it resets to `0` with every iteration, so after the loop it will only equal whatever the last number was, or zero if the last number wasn't divisible by three or five.
2. You don't need that many conditions. You can just use an or (`||`) with one `if`.

---

```
$total = 0;

for ($test = 1; $test <= 20; $test++) {
    if (($test % 3 == 0) || ($test % 5 == 0)) {
        $total += $test;
    }    
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `$test` to `$total`, so you can either do:
`$total = $total + $test;`
or `$total += $test;`, but not both!

You are also resetting `$total` each time you reset the loop, so you will want `$total = 0;` to be outside of your for-loop.

Give this a try:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
for ($test = 1; $test <= 20; $test++) {

    if (($test % 3 == 0) && ($test % 5 == 0)) {
    $total += $test;
    }
    elseif ($test % 3 == 0) {
    $total += $test;
    }
    elseif ($test % 5 == 0) {
    $total += $test;
    }

}

echo $total;

?>
```

Comment: So did this work because you made $total a Global variable? When I left $total in the for brackets, it just turned up 20. Tnx btw :)

Comment: The assignments will work fine, though they are more verbose than they need to be. The counter being reset inside the loop is the problem.

Comment: Sort of, when you set `$total = 0` inside the for-loop, you are resetting it to 0 every time you increase `test` by 1. If you want an accumulating sum, you can't reset the sum every time you add `test`, so you want to reset it to 0 BEFORE you begin to add `test` to `total`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$total` variable before entering for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in validating your code after it runs then I suggest this for ease-of-use:

```
$to_be_summed = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 1000; ++$i)
{
    if($i%3 === 0 && $i%5 === 0)
    {
        $to_be_summed[] = $i;
    }
}
echo array_sum($to_be_summed);

echo '<br><br>';

// See which numbers met the criteria
echo '<pre>'.print_r($to_be_summed, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: I don't know much about arrays yet, but this peaks my interest. Although this tests whether $i is divisible by 3&&5, it was easy to change to 3||5. I see a lot of people are using $i as a variable, is there any reason behind this, if I may ask?

Comment: @user3236492 Arrays are quite possibly the **BEST** thing about PHP; without them, PHP would be horrifically arduous to use. Think of an array as a list of items so instead of `$to_be_summed_1 = '3'; $to_be_summed_2 = '6';` you have `$to_be_summed[] = '3'; $to_be_summed[] = '6';` and now iterate `foreach($to_be_summed as $v){echo $v.'<br>';}`. `$i` is generally used in `for()` loops because it is the first letter of the word "increment". If you have a `for()` inside another `for()` then the inner `for()` should use `$j`, `$k`, and so forth to avoid overwriting the parent's `for()` incrementer.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely use this in further assignments.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

> text below is quoted

Rather than using range/loop based solutions you may wish to leverage more math than brute force.

There is a simple way to get the sum of multiples of a number, less than a number.

For instance, the sum of multiples of 3 up to 1000 are: 3 + 6 + 9 + ... + 999 Which can be rewritten as: 3* ( 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 333)

There is a simple way to sum up all numbers 1-N:

```
Sum(1,N) = N*(N+1)/2
```

So a sample function would be

```
function unitSum($n) {
    return ($n*($n+1))/2;
}
```

So now getting all multiples of 3 less than 1000 (aka up to and including 999) has been reduced to:

```
3*unitSum((int)(999/3))
```

You can do the same for multiples of 5:

```
5*unitSum((int)(999/5))
```

But there is a caveat! Both of these count multiples of both such as 15, 30, etc It counts them twice, one for each. So in order to balance that out, you subtract once.

```
15*unitSum((int)(999/15))
```

So in total, the equation is:

```
$sum = 3*unitSum((int)(999/3)) + 5*unitSum((int)(999/5)) - 15*unitSum((int)(999/15))
```

So now rather than looping over a large set of numbers, and doing comparisons, you are just doing some simple multiplication!

Answer (score -1):

Remove = from += your I think adding twice.